# When trying to get value from class '.o_value' to var val and print inside the jquery, works fine but outside jquery, not getting value

Tags: jquery

I have tried the below code but it seems doesn't work, pls go through the below code

```
var val = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var val = jQuery(".o_value input").val(); // for example value in class is 5

  val = parseInt(val);
  console.log(val); // works fine and it prints value- 5, which is correct
});
console.log(val); // outside jquery it does not print 5, why??.. pls advise
```

What should I need to do to fix this.

Comment: How many elements with `o_value input` class name do you have in your document? Is it possible that the element with this class is not loaded or does not have a value yet when you run this script?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the "ready" handler will not execute until the DOM has been completely constructed. When code outside the handler is encountered, it will run immediately.

As a result, your second `console.log(val);` (outside of the "ready" handler)  runs before the code in the handler,  at the time global variable (in your case `val`) hasn't been initialized, so its return undefined value.

So the answer is **no** you can't. That's how it works.